# Chrome Extensions - chrome.storage.sync alternative?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

Chrome's Web Store is full of "Sync" Extensions. Every one of them focuses on front-end data like bookmarks and tabs. What about the back-end data? Has anyone come across an extension that acts as an alternative to chrome.storage.sync? Of course I've searched google using a few dozen different search terms, but everything circles back to bookmarks and tabs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Being kind of an expert on extension API I still don't understand the question. However it looks like a software search request which is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @wOxxOm as far as I understood it is not a bad idea though, an extension that can be used like a local storage but with a cloud database

Comment: Even if your guess is right it doesn't make the question on-topic.

Comment: Do you mean something like [Google Keep](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-chrome-extens/lpcaedmchfhocbbapmcbpinfpgnhiddi), for instance?

Comment: I suppose in a way I would be looking for a "software" solution but it is more-so a service solution. Google provides the service that allows chrome.storage.sync to do what it does. Correct? I'm looking for that, but from an alternate provider. One that doesn't have such strict limits. If that goes against the rules then i'll remove the question or close it or whatever needs to be done. I am new here (in terms of asking questions), so I apologize if my question is off-topic.

Comment: The usual services are Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive. There is no special service for extensions.